Linphone Android SDK build
I am encountering linker errors when trying to build my CMake project for the Aarch64 (arm64) architecture. The errors indicate that certain x86_64 assembly files are incompatible with the Aarch64 architecture. Here is a sample of the errors I am encountering:
ld: error: ../simd/CMakeFiles/simd.dir/x86_64/jsimdcpu.asm.o is incompatible with aarch64linux
ld: error: ../simd/CMakeFiles/simd.dir/x86_64/jfdctflt-sse.asm.o is incompatible with aarch64linux
...
ld: error: too many errors emitted, stopping now

I understand that these errors occur because the x86_64 assembly files are not compatible with Aarch64. How can I resolve these errors and build my project successfully for the Aarch64 architecture?
